# "Perfect" .NET development environment?  

Tags: .net, version-control, development-environment

I've been given an early Christmas Present:
    Permission to step out of the development cycle to **reorganize** and **document** our application.
    I have complete freedom to restructure, refactor, and set up any amount of infrastructure I see fit.

If you had [carte blanche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carte_blanche), what's your "perfect" .NET development environment?

About the application:
VB.NET client-server application. (Windows Forms front end, ASPX Webservices back end)
    Currently using Visual Studio and SQL Server 2003 and... Visual SourceSafe.

I'd like to have some combination of:

    * Better versioning. (leaning towards Subversion)

    * Wiki or other system for bug tracking and documentation. (leaning towards [Trac](http://Trac) with Subversion)

    * Simplified build process and daily builds ([Visual Build](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Build)? [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl)?)

    * Version control for the SQL Server database

    * Upgrade to Visual Studio 2005 (or 2008)?

... for a small team of 5 or so developers

Comment: SQL Server 2003:  are you sure?  Last time I checked there is no such animal.

Comment: Maybe he means VS2003 and SQL Server 2000

Comment: haha. Yeah... I meant VS2003 & SQL2000.
My brain is a little blurry sometimes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend the following tools (mostly because it's what we're using):

- Visual Studio 2008
- SQL Server 2008
- [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/)
- [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)
- [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

We each work on our local machines and have a separate build server which monitors the Subversion repository (using CruiseControl.NET) and builds the latest revision on that server.

We use 'MSBuild Community Tasks' to embed the Subversion revision number in the assembly so that we can display it to the user.

The biggest 'holes' we have in our setup at the moment are in the database and in our automated testing.

Currently we all run off a central database server.  Ideally you should work towards having a script which re-creates your database under source control.  From what I gather, every time the build server rebuilds the site, it should also rebuild the database.  You should also have a script which will generate any test data you want in the database.

With database builds like this, you can all work on a local copy of the database, too.

You might want to take a look at the SQL Toolbelt (or parts of it) from [Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/) software - we use the SQL Compare tools to deploy schemas to live servers and I've been really impressed with them.

Good luck!

Comment: The redgate ones work much better than the ones built into VS2008 Database Ed. Good call.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are all leaning in the right direction.

Go with Visual Studio 2008.  It's very stable with SP1, and you can target both version 2 and version 3 of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 8):

No matter how much time and thought you put into this, you'll probably never end up with a "perfect" environment.  Each tool has their own quarks and issues.  Nevertheless, here is some food for thought:

Go to the latest and greatest version of Visual Studio, Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

If you are an MSDN subscriber, and have purchased the Team System Version of Visual Studio, you can install [Team Foundation Server](http://Team%20Foundation%20Server) (TFS).  TFS is a pretty slick product that is integrated into Visual Studio.  It uses Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS), which would give you the ability to have wikis, document repositories, etc. (basically a stripped down version of Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server).  TFS will also give you the newest version of Visual SourceSafe, which I have had no problems with, and Microsoft talks about it being able to scale to hundreds of thousands of users.  TFS Workgroup edition will allow you up to 5 developers to use without having to purchase a license.  Above 5 users, and you'll have to purchase licenses.  I'm also pretty sure you'd have to use SQL Server 2005 in order to run TFS, but I could be wrong.  We have TFS installed on a single box (our developer box), and have had no issues.

SO TFS Would give you:

- Collaboration
- Version Control
- Reporting on Project Status
- Issue Tracking
- Integration into Visual Studio
- A lot of other goodies

For your daily and continuous builds, I'd lean towards [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) (CC.NET).  We tried to use the build system built into TFS, but ran into many, many issues (I think mainly because of the way our projects are structured).  CruiseControl.NET was a breeze to install and configure, and works like a champ.  You can set it up for continuous building (each check-in triggers a build), and daily builds.  You may have to find some cleaver ways to make CruiseControl.NET do some of the more difficult tasks (like stopping a service, etc.), but it hasn't been able to do anything I've needed done.  It is also pretty extensible, so you can write some code to make it do what you want which is a nice feature.

Not sure about versioning of the database, but I'd assume you can use TFS Source Safe to achieve this.

Good luck!

Comment: "TFS will also give you the newest version of Visual source safe." What?

Answer (score 5):

Any perfect .NET development environment would have a copy of [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) installed.  I'm a recent convert, and **I love it**.

Answer (score 4):

I would cast a vote for Team Foundation Server. Then you have source control, automated builds and (kind of) bug tracking all in one package, that integrates very nicely with VS 2008. It has a rather steep price, though.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. When talking about .NET, there is no better IDE than Visual Studio. And VS2008 is the best of them. And for Visual Studio there is no better source control than TFS. Plus, its SO much more than just source control. The absurd price is the only downside.

Comment: +1, but the price is something microsoft should work on

Comment: "but the price is something microsoft should work on"-
yeah.. I'll be sure to submit a "Marketing Bug Report" to their team...

Answer (score 3):

My preference goes to the Visual Studio 2008 / Subversion / [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac) / Anck and Tortoise / [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) (TeamCity / [Bitten](http://bitten.edgewall.org/)) setup.

I'm not saying [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) isn't a great product, but I think it is 'bulky'. I switched recently from a Trac / Subversion solution to TFS and I prefer the first setup. There are details, but they make it nice to work with.

Example:

- TFS send mails for checkins and builds, in Trac there is an easy [timeline](http://trac.edgewall.org/timeline) feed. (There are **workarounds** for TFS.)
- when there is new checkin, click on the link (from the feed) and you are in the Trac environment. You see a nice [diff](http://trac.edgewall.org/changeset/7716) with the previous chancgeset. (where in TFS?)
- The integrated wiki is a very nice environment for internal documentation.
- [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) in the Tortoise client for your comments
- nice web interface to browse source, update documentation (was easy when I was at home)
- ...

The little details make it a much nicer tool for me.

I also say that the team was a small one (also 5 developers) and you need some time to setup. I agree that when you work with larger teams TFS is maybe preferable.

Answer (score 3):

On the development box

- Visual Studio 2008
- SQL Server 2008
- Red Gate [SQL Compare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Gate_Software#Products)
- Red Gate [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Gate_Software#Products)

On the server

- [SourceGear Vault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_%28revision_control_system%29)
- [FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz) (Wiki, releases, estimates, bug tracking)
- [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation for IDE and source control:

- VS2008 with SP1
- SubVersion, with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (for Windows Explorer) and [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (for VS2008)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a recent convert to SourceGear Fortress. It's inexpensive, fast, and reliable.

I love TFS for larger teams (>20 developers). I'm just starting to get my feet wet with Subversion, so I don't have anything to share yet, except that it was pretty easy to set it up.

Trac, however, was very difficult to get running. That's a matter of documentation, though, not the product itself.

Answer (score 1):

My choices would be:

> > Better versioning.

I'd pick [SourceGear Vault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vault_%28revision_control_system%29) - rock-solid, works like a charm, your source in stored in SQL Server databases --> can easily be backed up and is not flaky as Visual SourceSafe.

> > Wiki or other system for bug tracking and documentation.

From my personal experience: [FogBugz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FogBugz) is your best bet - simple, easy, quick to grasp, gets the job done nicely, just works and everybody just "gets it" without lengthy and expensive adaptation / customization and without much training - just works :-)

> > Simplified build process and daily builds (Visual Build? CruiseControl.NET?)

CruiseControl.NET is a great free option - if you don't mind speding a bit of $$$, I'd also look at FinalBuilder - either as a desktop or a server application.

> > Version control for the SQL Server database

--> use Vault! Works the same way. Use a great tool like Apex SQL Scripter or something similar to create and maintain your SQL to create and update the database schema, and put those SQL scripts into Vault.

> > Upgrade to Visual Studio 2005 (or 2008)?

Go with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on .NET 3.5 SP1 - solid and full of great new productivity features.

Just my $0.02

Answer (score 0):

We use SourceGear's Vault for version control and it works well for us as a small team.

For project/bug/support tracking we use OnTime 2008 from AxoSoft.

We also use ScrewTurn Wiki to document procedures and sample code/best practices.

For our build process, we haven't fully automated into a daily process because we don't generally work that way. However, for the beta and release builds, I just use NAnt to do a complete build for me after I update version numbers manually (I do this for better looking version numbers for our support team).

And definitely use Visual Studio 2008. The 2005 version really had a lot of issues on large VB projects (at least for us).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with VS2008 with SP1, SVN (with Ankh and Tortoise)

Look into [sandcastle](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/) / [docproject](http://www.codeplex.com/DocProject) for generating documentation.

CruiseControl works well.

As for sourcecontrol for the databases, you can use the database project type in VS2008 and use SVN (or other source control solution of your choice) to keep that under sourcecontrol.

Comment: Point of clarification, you'll want to look into Cruise Control .NET which is an Windows/IIS complement to the original Cruise Control project.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Subversion with [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) for bug tracking, project management, [FishEye and Crucible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/) for source browsing and code review, and it works out very well.

We are a team of 12 developers spread around. We are long time users of [FinalBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FinalBuilder) which we use to do all builds and automated deployment - a mix of VB.NET and Visual Studio 2008 projects, and it is working out exceptionally well for us. We target SQL Server 2005/2008  databases and keep the database objects in the source control repository. Most of the time we use the Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition combined with tools from Redgate and it works out pretty well for us - especially managing the change scripts and other stuff. For us TFS simply didn't work out - though your mileage might vary. We found it to be too cumbersome, difficult to customize workflow and rather than helping with the workflow had a bad tendency to get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Very yes on VS 2008 with SP1. I'd also highly recommend:

- [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) (absolutely zero learning curve coming from VSS, with all the benefits of SVN)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard a number of good things about TFS; however, there is also the cost factor. The tools you listed work very nicely with one another and are free.

One addition I would make is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for the Subversion client. Purists don't like it, but the fact that it integrates with the Windows shell's context menus (right clicks) makes it very easy to use.

For SVN versions, go with the 1.6 release that came out recently. Branching and merging have been improved with this version.

Trac is a great tool. Make sure to read up on [TracWiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki) and [TracLinks](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks) formatting rules for your SVN commit messages. Trac parses these messages so if you're commiting a fix for Ticket 123, adding '#123' to the SVN message allows Trac to link that commit (and all files associated with it) to the corresponding Trac tickets. This becomes especially usefull if and when you decide to move to delta releases.